# Android live wallpaper fade effect

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I would like to ask about fade and slide effect in live wallpaper.
How can I make fade in/ fade out or slide in/ slide out effect in live wallpaper when change between two images. 
If someone knows, please help me!

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With live wallpaper, you must handle these effects manually.  Fade in/fade out could be achieved by drawing two bitmaps into the same canvas and varying the alpha of the second bitmap.  I'm not sure what you mean by "slide" ... live wallpapers usually use an effect called parallax scrolling, which is facilitated by the onOffsetsChanged() callback...see the cube example in the SDK for a simple implementation.

Comment: Thanks so much ! I will try as you comment

Comment: @George Freeman: Can you please elaborate more on achieving the fade in/fade out effect? Some sample code would be really awesome.