# Display Image with Fade Effect in Android Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am trying to create a slideshow in Android using its `WallpaperService` class. I am using `Canvas` and `Bitmap` to display images. I am able to display images sequentially but I am unable to figure out a way to add fade in animation to the images while they change. I know how to animate `View`s in Android but I am unable to implement the same on `Canvas`. I tried looking for a similar question on SO and found one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338412/android-live-wallpaper-fade-effect) but it would have been great had the answer been a detailed one.

I'd be grateful if someone pointed me to a source that can help me overcome this problem.

**EDIT:**

I set the image on the `Canvas` as follows:

Inside the class extending `WallpaperService.Engine`, I do the following:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

            if (canvas != null) {
                canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
                Bitmap bitmap = //get bitmap
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    paint.setAlpha(alpha);
                    if (alpha < 255 ) {
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, width, height), paint);
                        bitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        bitmap.recycle();
                    }
                    alpha+=1;
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException ignore) {
            ignore.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
        handler.removeCallbacks(this);
    }
```

All I get is a black screen after this.

Comment: see `Paint#setAlpha`

Comment: I tried using it but it would help if a hint is given on how to use it. I have added some code to the question as well.

Comment: what is the value of `alpha`?

Comment: It starts with 0. I am new to threads as well, so I am not sure whether my approach to iterate the value of alpha and then calling drawBitmap() is correct.

Comment: the `run` method,  is it called by you? if so,  when?  in a loop?

Comment: Yes, the run method is called by me in an event listener.

Comment: what event listener?  how many times it is called?  can you be more verbose?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102688/discussion-between-androidnoob-and-pskink).